# Is there a way to delegate methods to the 'active' join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

Suppose I have posts, which have many categories through categorizations.  Suppose that I add a boolean column `primary` to `categorizations` in order to determine the primary category of a post.  But now I'm stuck dealing with the join model, when what I'd really like to do is something like this:

```
post = Post.first
primary_cat = post.categories.where(:primary => true)

post.categories.first.primary = true
post.save # would actually update the categorization, setting primary = true
```

There are all sorts of examples I could give you to show why this would be useful, but essentially I want to be able to interact with a model as though it is somehow merged with its join model.  Being able to say "What's the primary category?" or "OK this category will be the primary one" without ever touching the join model is the intuitive for me the think of this.

Is this even possible with Rails? Has anyone seen a effort to do this sort of thing before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like quest's solution except that setting it should just be `post.primary_category=` and should take a category object. Just setup a `has_one :primary_category` on post and you're golden.

Comment: Although I agree the setter should be there, then it doesn't save active state on both the join model and the post, which could be useful later.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is to create a set_primary(post) method on category that takes as its argument the post and boolean.

```
def set_primary(post)
  categorization = post.categorization.where('your opts hash here')
  categorization.primary = true
  categorization.save!
end


post.categories.first.set_primary(post)
```

Comment: Yeah that kinda solves the problem, but only one side of it. I was trying to see if a more holistic/integrated solution existed.

Answer (score 1):

Charlie Bowman does have the first piece of the puzzle with the set_primary logic on the Category model, however his setter doesn't unset the previous active category... In addition, the expensive part of Steve's problem, is actually just getting the primary category on each request. To get around that, I would also save the primary category id on the Post itself. That way you don't need to access the join model to figure out the primary category.

```
def set_primary_category(post)
  post.categorizations.each do |cat|
    if cat.post == post
      cat.primary = true
      cat.save!
      post.update_attribute(:primary_category_id, cat.category_id)
    else
      cat.update_attribute(:primary, false) if cat.primary
    end
  end
end
```

TO SET:

```
post.categories.first.set_primary(post)
```

TO ACCESS:

```
post.primary_category
```

Unfortunately I don't think anyone has made a gem that makes this easier for you to accomplish, but the logic is pretty straightforward. It also has the benefit of having access to the primary state in both the categorization and the post, so that you always have a fast way to access the data.

Also, I think its good to remember. You have a many to many relationship for posts/categories. But only a has_one relationship for post/primary_category. Whenever you have an access pattern like that, I like to try and stay away from the join model for the has_one, since it just isn't needed.

Comment: You might also want to look at association methods, they probably can accomplish what you need. Old school but still useful. http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2006/12/3/extend-your-activerecord-association-methods

Answer (score -1):

this question is probably a duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: attr_accessor for submodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610699/ruby-on-rails-attr-accessor-for-submodels), but basically [delegate](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1b819d32f6302e300da0188c4edb0f3b7bd48886/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L106) should be what you're looking for, with an additional callback on save.

Comment: I'm rather familiar with delegate, and I don't see how it could accomplish what I'm looking for.  A given category has many categorizations.  How will I know which categorization to delegate to?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry I have misinterpreted your question